# NATS.io Unity Videogame (player spawning and position tracking)

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, nats.io

I am developing a project which consists in a multiplayer videogame implemented with NATS.io messaging system (https://nats.io/) in Unity.

I am trying to spawn a player prefab in the map whenever a connection is made, but I have tried and I don't know what I'm making wrong. After spawning a player I would like to track its position so the other players can see where they are.

My code looks like this:

```
public class Launcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Launcher instance;
    private IConnection connection;

    public GameObject playerPrefab;

    private void EstablishConnection()
    {
        Options opt = ConnectionFactory.GetDefaultOptions();
        opt.Url = "nats://demo.nats.io:4222";
        opt.Name = "Nats Blitz";

        ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
        IConnection connection = cf.CreateConnection(opt);


        // Setup an event handler to process incoming messages.
        EventHandler<MsgHandlerEventArgs> handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            //This is where I think the player should spawn
            Instantiate(playerPrefab, PlayerSpawner.spawnPoint.position, PlayerSpawner.spawnPoint.rotation);
        };

        IAsyncSubscription subAsync = connection.SubscribeAsync("blitz.game.join", handler);
        connection.Publish("blitz.game.join", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Game connected!"));

    }

    public IConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        EstablishConnection();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
    }
}
```

But the only message I see from NATS console is

Received on "blitz.game.join"
Game connected!

and the prefab is not spawning.

What am I doing wrong? and Do anyone knows if this can be acomplished only by using NATS.io? If it do not, can you advise me on what other open source technologies can I combine in order to make my game work? (Use of NATS if mandatory but I can use other technologies too)

Thanks in advance :D

I am learning about NATS.io but I have tried to make other subscriptions, sending messages from the "Updated" method, but neither of them are getting executed.